# Diskpart selection issue

Tags: cmd, operating-system, windows-10

[image: cmd commands and response]

I am RE-INSTALLING windows 10 on my pc using a bootable pen drive. For which regarding the drive selection, I am selecting the drive " disk partition 3: windows". I am getting this problem where I cant install windows on that drive with error to be " windows cannot be installed on this drive. The drive is in GPT partition style "

To resolve that issue, I am to clean that drive through cmd. But what appears to be is even after typing the exact name of that specific drive, I cannot select it. Instead, if I select disk 0, I am able to select the entire hard drive.

I am not looking forward to cleaning the entire hard drive. Can someone help me out on this? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As on how to use diskpart:

```
list disk # to see disks
select disk 0 # to first select the disk
```

then you can do

```
list part #to see partition 
select part 3 # to select the partition you want
```

then you can delete it or what ever.
But I'm not sure that this will help with your problem. The problem you're having is the "partition style" GPT vs MBR.

I've found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-cannot-be-installed-on-this-disk-the/8fa72a3e-10c5-47da-a040-1e0db62af309) it says how to change the disk to MBR

```
list disk
select disk 0 # make sure of the right index
convert mbr   # this will change the partition style
quit
```

This should change your disk to MBR and thous allow you to proceed with the installation without encountering the problem you had before. Also should not result in data loss.

Comment: Thankyou lohmar.

Comment: If the answer helped, it would be appreciated if you'd give credit/vote it.

Comment: someone downvoted the question and even your answer.